# Enviar Array para BD

Tags: php, json, array

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou tentando passar um array que recupero de um JSON para o BD, mas não estou conseguindo identificar os objetos do Array, creio que esteja fazendo alguma coisa errada, fiz alguns testes com foreach mas não consegui sucesso, segue os cod's.

**HTML**

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>

<title>DataTable</title>

<style>
tfoot input {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
tfoot {
display: table-footer-group;
}
</style>

<?php include('container.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
<h2>DataTable</h2>
<div class="row">
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Horário</th>
      <th>Nº Telefone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="selectedDate" id="1">Data</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

**script.js**

```
// _START_ DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
"sAjaxSource": "data.php",
"bPaginate": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"iDisplayLength": 5,
"autoWidth": true,
"aoColumns": [
  {mData: [0]},
  {type: 'date-br',
  targets: 1},
  { "orderable": false, "targets": 2 }, // remove a ordenação
  { "orderable": false, "targets": 3 },
  ]
  });

// função para retornar o dados da tela em json
setInterval(function () {
var table3 = $('#example').tableToJSON();
var request =  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "teste.php",
  data: { array: table3},
  dataType: "html"
})    
request.done(function(resposta) {
  //resposta servidor
  console.log(resposta)
});
}, 6000); // está em segundos
```

**teste.php**

```
<?php
$array = ($_POST['array']);
print_r($array);
```

**Array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 
        [Data] => 
        [Horário] => 
        [Nº Telefone] => 
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 8010
        [Data] => 27/12/2017
        [Horário] => 14:58:27
        [Nº Telefone] => 1231530337
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 8010
        [Data] => 27/12/2017
        [Horário] => 14:56:52
        [Nº Telefone] => 1231530337
    )
)
```

Comment: Precisa fazer um foreach no `$array` depois acessa as chaves que deseja.

Comment: Eu tinha feito antes mas acabei passando valor errado e pensei que não ia da certo, revi a estrutura novamente e deu certo .-. `foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  var_dump($key." - ".$value["ID"]);
  var_dump($key." - ".$value["Data"]);
  var_dump($key." - ".$value["Horário"]);
  var_dump($key." - ".$value["Nº Telefone"]);
}`

Comment: **RESULTADO** `string(4) "0 - "
string(4) "0 - "
string(4) "0 - "
string(4) "0 - "
string(8) "1 - 8010"
string(14) "1 - 27/12/2017"
string(12) "1 - 14:58:27"
string(14) "1 - 1231530337"
string(8) "2 - 8010"
string(14) "2 - 27/12/2017"
string(12) "2 - 14:56:52"
string(14) "2 - 1231530337"
string(8) "3 - 8010"
string(14) "3 - 27/12/2017"
string(12) "3 - 10:53:14"
string(15) "3 - 11993229733"` nesse caso eu já consigo fazer o insert dos dados no banco ? Obrigado

Comment: @DiogoMoura Da pra ver nada aqui nos comentarios, melhor editar sua pergunta.

Comment: @DiogoMoura, dei uma estudada nesse PostgreSQL, criei um banco com uma tabela ligacoes porém ficou faltando criar a tabela callcent_queuecalls para que eu possa testar. Se vc puder fornecer o sql para criar essa tabela e um `ìnsert` com os dados,  me pouparia tempo pois vou ter que estudar os tipos de dados para ficar tudo nos conformes. No entanto, editei minha resposta publicando a pagina teste.php que está funcionando redondo.

Comment: Acabei de atualizar o GIT com os insert, vc pode me enviar o SQL da tabela que você criou por favor, tentei inserir aqui com esse código que vc atualizou no meu banco de teste e não deu certo, pode ser que o meu bd de teste esteja errado, obrigado.

Comment: Como ainda não conheço os tipos de dados  do PostgreSQL, criei 4 campos, cod, data, hora e telefone tudo tipo  `character(15)`. Mudei o array na resposta e acredito que tenha ficado como vc colocou na sua pergunta.

Comment: Crie uma tabela para teste com 4 campos `cod, data, hora e telefone` e rode o código da minha resposta para ver se insere.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo eu tinha feito os testes antes com o array manual e eles insere normalmente, rodei novamente com o seu cód e ta OK enviou para o banco, mas ai quando puxo os dados da minha tabela como array ele n envia pro banco e o array está igual ao do seu cod dei um `print_r` e a estrutura é a mesma a que está na minha pergunta, eu coloquei para pegar os dados por determinado tempo no script, será que ele não está ativando a minha pagina teste.php que faz o envio de dados para o BD ? pelo menos o `print_r` da pagina php está retornando no console.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo CONSEGUI!! fiz o seguinte, `$array = ($_POST['array']);
  $json_e = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  $json_d = json_decode($json_e, true);
  print_r ($json_d); //teste`

Comment: Beleza, sucesso ai pra você!!!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo muito obrigado pela ajuda, sucesso pra vc também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**  teste.php

Fiz um teste com o array conforme mostrado no código abaixo, e está funcionando redondo

```
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=call_lost user=diogom password=morfeu00");

    $array = (

    Array
    (
    "0" => Array
        (
            "ID" => "",
            "Data" => "",
            "Horário" => "",
            "Nº Telefone" => ""
        ),
    "1" => Array
        (
            "ID" => "8020",
            "Data" => "27/12/2017",
            "Horário" => "14:58:27",
            "Nº Telefone" => "1231530337"
        ),
    "2" => Array
        (
            "ID" => "8020",
            "Data" => "27/12/2017",
            "Horário" => "17:52:52",
            "Nº Telefone" => "1231530337"
        ),
    )

);


$values = array();
// construção dos values a serem inseridos na declaração insert
foreach ($array as $rowValues) {
  //se algum campo de um bloco for nulo, esse bloco não será salvo no banco
  $valido = false === array_search(false , $rowValues, false);
  if ($valido == true){
    $values[] = "(" ."'". implode('\',\' ', $rowValues) . "')";
  }
}
//declaração insert
$sql = "INSERT INTO ligacoes (cod,data,hora,telefone) VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);
$result = pg_query($sql);
```

> adaptei o array conforme mostrado na sua pergunta

Comment: Desculpa a demora para responder, estou tendo o seguinte retorno `INSERT INTO ligacoes (, , , ) VALUES ('8010',' 27/12/2017',' 14:58:27',' 1231530337'), ('8010',' 27/12/2017',' 14:56:52',' 1231530337'), ('8010',' 27/12/2017',' 10:53:14',' 11993229733'), ('8010',' 27/12/2017',' 10:44:05',' 11993229733'), ('8010',' 27/12/2017',' 08:01:37',' Anonymous')` o campo $fields está retornando vazio, tentei substituir pelo no nome das minhas colunas mas também não está gravando no banco, criei uma pag teste para verificar o INSERT no BD e está OK.

Comment: sim, fiz esse teste colocando os valores das colunas e também não inseriu.

Comment: Quais são os nomes das colunas?

Comment: Pode postar seu formulario na pergunta?

Comment: Ficou assim `$sql = "INSERT INTO ligacoes (cod, data, hora, telefone) VALUES " . implode (', ', $values);`

Comment: Não estou utilizando um form, esses dados vem de uma tabela Jquery(DataTables) onde uso a API TableToJSON e passo para um AJAX ai onde envio para o PHP e que agora estou tentando gravar em outro BD

Comment: acabei de fazer um teste aqui com nomes das colunas no insert e deu certo também

Comment: Mas não tem jeito de ser um array na pagina do insert?

Comment: Na pagina que fiz de teste também deu certo `$sql = "INSERT INTO ligacoes (cod, data, hora, telefone) VALUES (142, '01/402/2017', '401:02:03', '314523152')";
pg_query($conn, $sql);
pg_close($conn);` desse jeito inseriu no BD, mas quando é para passar os valores automaticamente da tabela não insere.

Comment: Se puder coloque o HTML na pergunta, fui

Comment: Vou colocar, obrigado pela ajuda e meus pêsames.

Comment: @DiogoMoura, infelizmente com o que esta postado na pergunta não dá para fazer testes

Comment: Vou organizar o cod no pastebin e coloco o link aqui.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diogom-42/4ed9c329acfe28bd948e7faf9a50a94b  segue o link com o code completo do projeto, obrigado.

Comment: @DiogoMoura, seu servidor de banco de dados é PostgreSQL, o meu é MySQL, seu projeto não funciona comigo. Porém fiz o seguinte: coloquei diretamente na pagina teste.php o seu array e rodei no servidor (com MySQLi) e salvou no banco. Repare que no array `0` coloquei os nomes das colunas. Fiz um pastbin https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd1bdf99646c93d888019f3f3bb625e9 O resultado foi esse veja em https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwCGQ.png Repa

Comment: @DiogoMoura, dei uma olhada no meu servidor e descobri que tem lá o PostgreSQL Databases, vou tentar criar um banco lá !!!

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, estou aqui também fazendo alguns testes se caso eu conseguir algo posto aqui.